# concatenate in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

is this possible? sorry if wronged question

I have a column A
where I want to see if A is not null then
I would like to add 'great'before the value of A
like for example:

```
A has value of 100 than,
A should be great100
```

I tried below code so far but is passing error"'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name" :

```
UPDATE #TABLE SET A = CONCAT('great', A)  where A is not null
```

help me please how to concatenate ,Thank you

Answer I got it,firstly Thanks to you all

```
UPDATE #TABLE
SET A= 'great' + (A)
where A is not null
```

Comment: Can you provide table structure and sample data?

Comment: A is int or varchar column?

Comment: Concat only works with 2012 onward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE #TABLE 
SET A = 'great' +  value   
where A is not null
```

Comment: perfect ..Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You do it in CASE statement:

```
select 
CASE  
     WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN 'Great' + CONVERT(varchar(10), A)
END  as A_VALUE
from ......
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx